# 'contenttypes': None in MIGRATION_MODULES but "Table 'django_content_type' doesn't exist" error

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-contenttypes

I have a new project with django and I want to get ride of the auth_* and django_* tables.

I want the applications listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` so I used

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'admin': None,
    'auth': None,
    'contenttypes': None,
    'default': None,
    'sessions': None,
    'authtoken': None,
}
```

My next step is to `makemigrations myapp` and then run the `migrate` command, but at some point I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'django_content_type' doesn't exist")
```

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: have you added 'django.contrib.contenttypes' app in your installed apps in django settings?

Comment: Yes, my installed apps is like this:  

    `INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'myapp',
        'rest_framework',
        'rest_framework.authtoken',
        'rest_auth',
        'corsheaders',
    ]`

Comment: then remove it from there and try again @Adrian

Comment: Now when I execuete `migrate` command I get this error: `Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

Comment: did you removed it from MIGRATION_MODULES?

Comment: If I remove it from the MIGRATION_MODULES then it creates the table in the database

Comment: it won't create a table if you have removed it from Installed app

Comment: I can't do that because when I use `from rest_framework.views import APIView
` at some point it calls the contenttype app